# Screen scraping a separate program

Tags: excel, vba

I have this application called IRESS that has data that I then manually copy and paste to a spreadsheet to do certain calculations. I was wondering if there is any possible way of automating this process.

Comment: Well there's programs like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). Are you familiar with programming? Does IRESS have a way to export data or receive queries? Please add more details in your question, including what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is a web services interface to IRESS which you can find more about [here](https://webservices.iress.com.au/). So if you send a correctly formatted message to IRESS, it will respond with a message containing the data you requested and you can then update your spreadsheet with that data

Comment: Seems like IRESS is working on creating an excel add in for the market share data. Its coming out mid next year.